# router-view not listing component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to get basic routing going in Vue. I include 3 file listings that are faulty somewhere. If I include  in app.vue I get the foo component in the browser. If I do as indicated in the code below with  I get:

[image]

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Foo from './components/Foo';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Foo }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">

    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Foo from './components/Foo'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Foo,
  },
}
</script>
```

**Foo.js**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>string happens</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Foo',
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to Import it in your app.vue file once you have mentioned it in your route.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are importing `Foo` inside `App.vue`, but you are not using it there. Simply remove that import and the error will go away.

Comment: I removed the import and I managed to compile but the page does not come up. I see in chrome there is an exception.
'''
App.vue?234e:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foo is not defined
    at eval (App.vue?234e:13)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:875)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:786)
    ...
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (App.vue?bff9:1)
    at Module../src/App.vue (app.js:956)
'''

Comment: Did you also remove it from:
`components: {
    Foo,
  },`

Comment: I removed 
import Foo from './components/Foo' from <script>... </script> in app.vue
Nothing else

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change the app.vue code as below. not easy as a newby:-(

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```